# trouble with java program and toString()

Tags: java, tostring

I am trying to create a program that creates a class that represents a rectangle. A rectangle is specified by the `coordinates (x, y)` of its
Top left corner and its width and height. This class will be used to create many rectangle objects,
And it must feature:

- Dynamic fields (variables) to store x, y, the width and the height as fractional numbers;
- A constructor with parameters that provide x, y, the width and the height;
- A function that returns the area of the rectangle;
- A function that returns the length of the perimeter of the rectangle; and
- A function that returns a string representation of the rectangle, the four numbers, within a pair of parentheses, separated by commas. This function must be named `toString()`.

• Write, in a separate class, a main method that accepts the four numbers as command line arguments,
Instantiates a rectangle object, and prints the string representation of the rectangle, the area and
the perimeter.

The output should look like this:

```
$ java TestRect 1 2 3 4
rectangle = (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
area = 12.0
perimeter = 14.0
$
```

This is what I have so far

```
public class TestRect {

public static void main(String[] args) {


  double base = 0;
  double height = 0;
  double area = 0;
  double perimeter = 0;


  base = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);

  height = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);

  area = (base * height);

  perimeter = 2 * (base + height);



  System.out.println("The Area of Rectangle is : "
              + area);

  System.out.println("The Perimeter of Rectangle is : "
              + perimeter);

   }

}
```

I cant figure out how to do the toString part neither can I figure out what the x,y part is about. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you have so far for the "class that represents a rectangle"? That's the first part of your assignment. You need to show some effort on that before asking for help.

Comment: You can't figure out how to do the toString part of what? Your class?

Comment: What does "figure out what the x,y part is about." mean?

Comment: [This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_tostring.htm), [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html).

Comment: Are you learning on your own, or is this for a class? You have a lot to learn about classes and functions before you can do this.

Comment: Aside from major programming concepts, though, where the questions refer to `x` and `y`, they're referring to the coordinates (location) of the rectangle. E.g. x=0 and y=0 means the rectangle is in the upper-left corner of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. This is not for an assignment. I am merely trying to learn java from my brothers assignments. Sorry if anyone misunderstood. I dont have any classes which is why I asked the questions. its purely my own understanding about java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, are you maybe also new to object oriented programming? Because what you did is more like a c program (actually it even pretty much is...)

You should not let your main() - method do the logic for you, this should be contained in the class' methods.

Try to build it somewhat like the following:

```
public class TestRect {

  private double base;
  private double height;
  private double area;
  private double perimeter;

  public TestRect (double base, double height) {
     this.base = base;
     this.height = height;
     getPerimeter;
     getArea;
  }

  public double getPerimeter () {
     perimeter = 2 * (base + height);
     return perimeter;
  }

  public double getArea () {
     area = (base * height);
     return area;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     // here you can create a string just as you want it to look like
     return yourCreatedString;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      TestRect test = new TestRect(3.0, 4.0);
      System.out.println(test.toString());
   }

}
```

Maybe you should also read something about object oriented concepts... [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)